# GKE gke-gcloud-auth-plugin

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to connect to a cluster and I'm getting the following error:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster1 --region europe-west2 --project my-project
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
CRITICAL: ACTION REQUIRED: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin, which is needed for continued use of kubectl, was not found or is not executable. 
Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
kubeconfig entry generated for dbcell-cluster.
```

I have installed Google Cloud SDK 400, kubektl 1.22.12, gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.3.0, and also setup /~.bashrc with

`export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True`

```
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version
Kubernetes v1.24.0-alpha+f42d1572e39979f6f7de03bd163f8ec04bc7950d
```

but when I try to connect to the cluster always I'm getting the same error, any idea here?

Thanks

---

The cluster exist in that region, also I verfied the env variable

with

```
echo $USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN
True
```

I installed the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin using gcloud co`mponents install... I do not know what more can I check

[gcloud components list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55mjc.png)

Comment: Linux? What do you get from `echo ${USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN}`? You can `export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True` in the current session too to ensure that it's effective. What do you get from e.g. `ls -la $(which gke-gcloud-auth-plugin)`? Does the cluster exist in that region (`gcloud container clusters describe ...`)?

Comment: Can you run `which gke-gcloud-auth-plugin && which gcloud` and post the results, please? Also `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem by removing my current `kubeconfig` context for GCP.

1. Get your context name running:

   kubectl config get-contexts
2. Delete the context:

   kubectl config delete-context CONTEXT_NAME
3. Reconfigure the credentials

   gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --region REGION --project PROJECT

The warning message should be gone by now.